# How to add floating action button on the right-bottom side of the screen using material ui in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add `FloatingActionButton` on right bottom side of the screen. I am using this library http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import FloatingActionButton from "material-ui/FloatingActionButton";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import * as strings from "./Strings";
import styles from "./Styles";
import ContentAdd from "material-ui/svg-icons/content/add";

const AppBarTest = () =>
  <AppBar
    title={strings.app_name}
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
  />;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBarTest />
          <FloatingActionButton style={styles.fab}>
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
        </div>

      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Styles.js

```
const style = {
    fab: {
        backgroundColor: '#000000'
    },
};

export default style;
```

## Question 1

It is showing `FloatingActionButton` on top-left side, I want to make this on right-bottom side. What is the way to do this ?

## Question 2

Why style is not applying on `FloatingActionButton` ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the top and left auto styles? And are your styles even exported from styles.js?

Comment: @JeroenWienk I think style is not setting properly. I exported also but no change. What's wrong here ? `const fabStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#000000'
};

module.exports = fabStyle;`

Comment: @JeroenWienk See I have updated question with updated code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this style:

```
const fabStyle = {
    right: 20,
    position: 'fixed'
};
```

and later u use margin, top... but don't use auto on `position: fixed`

Comment: Do you have an idea why backgroundColor is not working on it http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button rest things are working. I am setting it as ` backgroundColor: '#000000'`

Comment: Try this:`<FloatingActionButton backgroundColor='#CCC' style={styles.fab}>
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>`

Comment: FloatingActionButton has a personal config in ur props to Background Color :D